# Ionic PouchDB gives CORS error for remote CouchDB

Tags: debian, couchdb, cors, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm getting this error from my ionic serve console.

> 733291   error    PouchDB error: the remote database does not seem to have CORS enabled. To fix this, please enable CORS:  http:// pouchdb .com/errors.html#no_access_control_allow_origin_header

I followed [this guide](http://www.matteomattei.com/install-couchdb-1.6.x-on-debian-7-wheezy/#comment-2240209361) to install couchDB on my bridged Debian7.8 virtualbox guest because the apt-get couchDB was version 1.2, and I've read that CORS somehow doesn't work in 1.2.

Here is a screenshot of the ionic/pouchDB output and the http headers giving a problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vok8rih830tsodq/cors.png?dl=0

In my index.html, right before including my app.js, I have

```
<script src="lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```

In app.js, I have

```
var localDB = new PouchDB("todos");
var remoteDB = "http://admin:mysecretpassword@192.168.1.4:5984/todos";

...

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    ...
    localDB.sync(remoteDB,{live:true});
```

I verified the remote CORS is working using monsur's cors-api from my client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this was a bug I introduced in 4.0.1. The bug is that it emits a warning when really everything is A-OK. I was trying to be helpful to people who run into CORS errors and don't understand what they're seeing, but I ended up confusing a lot of people who were getting a spurious warning and didn't understand why. (It has to do with not being able to distinguish CORS errors from normal HTTP timeouts.)

Anyway, if you upgrade to 4.0.2+ the warning will go away.

Comment: Good to hear from you! Learning dev stuff in my free time and this cors stuff still gives me trouble (recently with fb app testing). Anyhow, I tested with both 4.0.2 and 4.0.3 and I'm still getting the error. Sometimes it emits consistently on page refresh. It's OK for my couchdb Cors credentials=false right?

Comment: Please file a bug; it sounds like maybe we should remove the warning altogether, if it emits a lot of false negatives.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem with PouchDB 4.01 and Cloudant (hosted CouchDB). CORS is enabled on Cloudant and this error happens at random several times throughout the day. I spent almost 2 hours with Cloudant knowledgable technical support and they confirmed it is a PouchDB error (bug?), not a problem on the CouchDB server.

Comment: Mine is a little more frequent then that (page refresh, but maybe due to bad implementation? I have to look back..). It's good to know this seems to be a general warning with PouchDB and not couchdb. In case you didn't see, @nlawson added some insight above about 4.01.